# How to pipe output of active stream to other commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to pipe an active stream to another command (maybe a bash script), but it always wants to wait for the entire stream to finish before it processes the command. s.g. I can do this:

```
tail file.log | grep keyword | xargs -L 1 echo ...
```

and it correctly outputs the matching rows from file.log, preceded by "...". Obviously I don't want to just echo, that's just to simplify the example (I would replace that by a custom bash script). Now, when I try this:

```
tail -f file.log | grep keyword
```

this works, in that is outputs matching rows, then pauses until file.log changes, then it outputs any new matching lines. However, if I try this:

```
tail -f file.log | grep keyword | xargs -L 1 echo ...
```

It outputs nothing - I presume it's waiting for the stream opened by tail -f to end. I have tried this as well:

```
tail -f file.log | grep keyword | while read line; do echo...$line; end
```

with no change in behavior. I've read on other questions here that this should work. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, is there some difference because of that? How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `xargs` expects input from standard input, hence it is waiting for the stream to end. One way to make it work is by means of [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), because ...

> Process substitution is a form of redirection where the input or output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary file.

So you should try:

```
while IFS= read -r newline; do echo $newline | grep keyword | cat >> filename  ; done < <(tail -f file.log)
```

which dispenses with `xargs` altogether.

Comment: That works perfectly! I had seen the "< <(...)" syntax elsewhere, but didn't understand what it meant (or why the space in the middle was important). Thanks for the explanation!